# How to know if a time series collection is successfully created on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

```
        await conn.db("db_ts").collection("col_ts", {
          timeseries: {
            timeField: "timestamp",
            metaField: "metadata",
          },
        });
```

After this collection is created and data written to it, I have no indicator that it is a time series collection.

I know that on Atlas if I create a time series collection using the UI, there will be an icon and it would explicitly say time series collection. But there isn't any such indicators when I create the `col_ts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command [`db.getCollectionInfos()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/#db.getcollectioninfos--).

For a time series collection, the `type` field will have a value `timeseries`

```json
[
  ...
  {
    name: 'col_ts',
    type: 'timeseries',
    options: { timeseries: [Object] },
    info: { readOnly: false }
  }
  ...
]
```